# Mongo DB Atlas Mongoose credentials must be an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After removing Mongoose-package and re-installing it again I got stuck with an error.

The error I get seems to conflict with the instruction on [Mongo DB Atlas instruction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/). where to place username and password in the dbURI.

error:

> MongoParseError: credentials must be an object with 'username' and 'password' properties

This is my connection:

```html
 const dbURI =  "mongodb+srv://admin:mypass@cluster0.iujq0.mongodb.net/myApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

const options = {
    auth: { authSource: 'admin'},
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,        
}    

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect(dbURI, options)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The error indicates to place the username and password to the option object

I use node v 19.3 and Mongoose 6.8.2.

Comment: If the credentials are in the `dbUri`, you shouldn't have to provide them separately. What happens if you remove the `auth` property from options and don't pass a third argument to `mongoose.connect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
const options = {
  autoIndex: false, // Don't build indexes
  maxPoolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Keep trying to send operations for 5 seconds
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
  family: 4 // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
};
mongoose.connect(uri, options)
```

According to the official [Mongoose documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options) these are options-object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the username and the password in the connect method of mongoose since it has already been inserted in the URL itself. In another way, there is no need to add any options when connecting to your Atlas.

Here is an example:

```html
 const dbURI =  "mongodb+srv://admin:mypass@cluster0.iujq0.mongodb.net/myApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

const options = {
    auth: { authSource: 'admin'},
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,        
}    

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect(dbURI, options)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: ea that s what I did.. I did change my  code example. stil error